# Cannot log into Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to log into titanium studio and I keep getting the following error: The login server returned and error. Please consult the troubleshooting page for more information.  Is there something wrong with the server that will be fixed soon or is it something else?

Comment: please provide some more information (OS, Version) and try to run 'appc info' and see if there is any problem (just to make sure the everything around studio is setup correctly). Are you using a firewall/proxy? Was it working before or a new user/install?

Comment: Hello, Can you try logging in through terminal? Run "appc login". See if you can log in. please comment of your findings.

Comment: Please note this is not for appcelerator but for titanium studio.  I talked to appcelerator support and they said they no longer support titanium and I would not be able to log into it anymore.  Guess it is time to import the app into appcelerator.  Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium Studio has been discontinued on June 1 2015. You might have still been able to login since we needed the APIs it used for other legacy services we're gradually shutting down.